# Re-displaying after fadeOut

Tags: jquery

Please can I affirm that I am doing this correctly:

I have a message that I wish to fadeOut after it has been displayed.

The jQuery fadeOut sets display: none once the opacity is zero.

Thus when I want to display that same message again by setting visibility: visible the message won't display because display: none is still set.

So this is what I did:

```
        $("#message6").fadeOut(600, function(){
            $("#message6").css("display","");
            $("#message6").css("visibility","hidden");              
        });
```

This works just fine. It doesn't seem very elegant.

Am I missing something here? Is there a neat way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/T3Vm6/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
$("#message6").fadeOut(600);
```

And to show your message again:

```
$("#message6").show();
```

Comment: Ah well because I am setting the visibility: visible in the first instance. This may well be what I have been missing I should be using show instead in the first instance.

Comment: I only use visibility when my element should still reserve space in my DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Why not something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myLabel').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).html(""); //reset the label after fadeout
        });
    });​
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bXuMM/)**

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying and if I was setting the content of the message dynamically this would indeed do the job. But this is a fixed message.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had strange problems with jQuery's `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` methods, so usually I just animate the opacity. There's nothing wrong with this approach if you're just hiding and showing things.

```
$('#message6').animate({opacity:0}, 200);
```

If you don't want any sort of fading animation, you can just use the `.hide()` and `.show()` methods, or `.css({opacity:0})`, or an `.animate()` method with `0` animation duration.

Comment: As with @ Simon, I think you expose the error of my ways I have not been using .hide .show.